# Android - width and height must be > 0 in Image File compression

Tags: android, image-compression

I am compressing an image which is taken from the Gallery using a method which works most of the times. Here's the code :

```
public static Uri compressImage(Context context, Uri inputUri){
    String realPath = UtilityUriHelper.getPath(context, inputUri);
    File realFile = new File(realPath);

    File compressedImg = new Compressor.Builder(context)
            .setMaxHeight(1920)
            .setMaxWidth(1920)
            .setQuality(70)
            .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
            .build()
            .compressToFile(realFile);

    return Uri.fromFile(compressedImg);
}
```

So the error happen sometimes when I pick the same image over and over again. And the error is `width and height must be > 0`

I don't really understand why, sometimes it happens sometimes it doesn't.

If I have to do the checking on width and height, how to get the width and height before it's sent into Compressor.Builder()? Or I should do something else here?

Comment: Convert it to bitmap.

Comment: I need to upload it to server as a file.. Any other solution?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299490/android-reduce-file-size-for-camera-captured-image-to-be-less-than-500-kb)

Comment: whe you are picking the same image, you are working on same thread or different threads ?

Comment: I think it should be in the same thread as it is not an Async. I'm not proficient with threading so I might be wrong